# Error "unable to get property value of undefined or null reference" while accessing a hidden field using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net

I open a dialog window but I am not able to pass the value of hidden field. It is gving me error of undefined or null reference. I use function openA() in code behind to access it. When openA() is executed, the value is not available anywhere.  When I click the button to call openA() at first instance, I have access to the value assigned but later on it no longer has access. Any help is appreciated, below is the code.

Vb.Net Code:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "showModalDialog open function ", "openA();", True)
```

.Aspx Code

```
   function openAceitar() {
        debugger;


        try {

            <%--var hfPCID = document.getElementById("<%= hfPCID.ClientID%>").value;--%>

            //var hfID = $('#hfPCID').value


            var hfID = document.getElementById('<%=hfPCID.ClientID %>').value;

            var url = '<%=Request.ApplicationPath%>/FolderA/PopUps/myPopUpName.aspx?txtABCD=' + document.formMyForm.txtABCD.value  + '&hfPCID=' + hfID;
            var popupFeatures = 'scroll: yes; status: no; center: yes; resizable: no; dialogWidth: 800px; dialogHeight: 600px;'
            var popupWindow = window.showModalDialog(url, window, popupFeatures);

        } catch (e) { alert(e.message) }



   }
```

error message: "unable to get property value of undefined or null reference"

Comment: <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPCID" runat="server" value="false" Visible="false" />

Comment: I tried all sorts of configurations of getElementById argument, with single and double quotes: 'hfPCID'   "hfPCID"    '<%=hfPCID.ClientID %>'  "<%=hfPCID.ClientID %>" and with no quotes as well as jQuery

Comment: Did you try assigning a default value at page load?

Comment: Ruchi i cant as it is avalue dependent on a return from a function!

Comment: just to clarify on the code above you can see openAceitar() but it's openA() it's just a typo.

Comment: problem solved by a colleague of mine, he toke Visible="false" off of <asp:HiddenField ID="hfPCID" runat="server" value="false" Visible="false" /> and  now it works